# Can the Eclipse GWT plugin be configured to warn when you use non-emulated methods

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, warnings

Currently eclipse will happily let you use methods that aren't actually available in the compiled version because they're not emulated, resulting in a runtime failure. Can the GWT plugin be configured to warn/error on such usage?

Comment: I wish it could, would be handy.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and if I recall correctly the compile log warned about the issue.
I suggest you set the GWT log level to Info or Trace.
Go to: Google -> GWT Compile Project -> Compiler & Shell -> Log level.